# Android Wear Notification generated from the Wear don't Vibrate

Tags: android, wear-os

In my wear app I generate a notification to show the results of a process.

I have tried to set 
`Notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)` and `Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE`
and also `notification.setVibrate(PATTERN)` but no luck. The notification don't vibrates.

Of course, I have declared the VIBRATE permission in the manifest.

When I try to use the Vibrate service to vibrate, it works fine, but it vibrates every time, and I don't need to vibrate if the user has disabled the wear vibration at settings.

Please, how to make the notification (generated from the wear) to vibrate or how to get the vibration setting?

Comment: Try to set the notification priority to higher...

Answer (score 0):

two way your can try:
1. write vibrate permission in you phone app
2. sign your wear apk, apk which use debug key does not allow the VIBRATE in the watch
personal points

Comment: Also don't works. Notification.SetDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE) or Notification.vibrate(XX) don't works if Notification is created from the wear (not from the phone).

Answer (score 0):

1. you must set permision in Androidmanifest.xml

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
2. Add Code (I have a button when you click on phone, A notification and vibrate will active on watch)

   ```
       Button wearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wearButton);
        wearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           int notificationId = 001;
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_background);
           NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
           style.bigPicture(bitmap);



           //big image
           NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                   new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)

                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baby)
                   .setContentTitle("Title")
                   .setContentText("Android Wear Notification");
           notificationBuilder.setStyle(style);

           //Vibration
           notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

           //Ton
          // notificationBuilder.setSound(R.);

           NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                   NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
           notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
       }
   });
   ```

Remember: you should seperate smart watch from the charging plate

I have a complete project if you wan you can download https://app.box.com/s/veb68n0uzxcmotyo0rmfrxgyoig032lc